# Python download file from server to my computer

Tags: python, file, download, urllib

I have a server, which is running perfectly in this address (example): http://stackoverflow.cloud.com

And I have some files in this address which I would like to be download from there to my computer. I installed in the server the IIS and I can access to the files this way:
http://stackoverflow.cloud.com/files/nameOfFile.png

With this last URL I would like to download the file to my computer.

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve('http://stackoverflow.cloud.com/files/nameOfFile.png', 'C:\\myFile.png')
```

With this code instead of saving the file to my computer, it saves the file in the **harddisk of the server**.

I tried the module Webbrowser, but **I'm working with python version 2.6** and Webbrowser is for 3.2 or something.

Any other idea of how I can accomplish this?

Comment: did you look at `urllib2.urlopen`?

Comment: Where are you running that code? If you're running it on the server, of course it will download it there. If you run it on your local computer, that's where it will download it to.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, you're right. I'm running the code on the server, but I'm running the website in my computer. So, how can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Are you using a framework for the website or just python?

If it is a framwork like django you can return the data you want and specify a mimetype so that the data will be downloaded to the client computer.

Comment: Hello @nachshon, I'm not using any framework. I'm coding for the platform "OpenERP" which have de version 2.6 of python.

Comment: It's hard to say how you can achieve what you're trying to do, because I don't understand what you're trying to do. The server can't "download" a file to the client, the client can only request one from the server. Since you can already access the file via the URL you give, I'm not sure what else you actually need.

Comment: @DanielRoseman What you don't understand? The server contains everything (the code of python and the files generated - nameOfFile.png). My doubt is how to generate a download so the client can download the files from the server to his local machine?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I never tried using urllib before but I can guide you to read the [documentation for the `urllib.urlretrieve` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) in the Python standard library:

> urllib.urlretrieve(url[, filename[, reporthook[, data]]])
>
> Copy a network object denoted by a URL to a local file, if necessary. If the URL points to a local file, or a valid cached copy of the object exists, the object is not copied. Return a tuple (filename, headers) where filename is the local file name under which the object can be found, and headers is whatever the info() method of the object returned by urlopen() returned (for a remote object, possibly cached). Exceptions are the same as for urlopen().

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Seems that openERP has is own way of popup links:

```
return { 'type': 'ir.actions.act_url', 'url': 'http://stackoverflow.cloud.com/files/nameOfFile.png'}
```

Thank you all.